# Recompilation upon Comment Modification

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, comments

I have a header which a lot of files depend on. I changed a comment and this caused full recompilation. I heard that whether the code requires recompilation depends on the comparison between compilation date and current date, but is there a way so that I can freely modify comments and keep VS2008 from recompiling everything?

Comment: "comparison between compilation date and current date": what current date?

Comment: To my knowledge, no such system exists anywhere. It would be nice, but it would also slow down the more common case, and I'm sure that it would be a net time loss in the long run.

Comment: Comparison is between the modified date on the files.  If a header has a more recent date than a file it is included into then that file needs to be compiled.  The contents of the files not checked before compilation.  TLDR no.

Comment: @wasthishelpful I got the words wrong, I meant 'the date the file was last compiled' and 'the date of current compilation'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to freely modify comments and keep Visual Studio (any version) from recompiling "because only comments have changed". Tracking what has actually changed is the job of the version control system (e.g. git or SVN).

Your question seems to arise from working on a solution that takes a long time to build (incrementally or fully), and there are effective ways of improving that situation.

This [Visual C++ PCH howto](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/precompiledheaders.html) helped me reduce our build times significantly. Also we apply all 3 points explained in [this article](http://aprogrammers.blogspot.de/2009/05/speeding-up-build-times-in-visual.html) and on top of all that, also use [IncrediBuild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IncrediBuild) (commercial product). Each of these steps helped us keep C++ build times in check.